# How did the events at the end of Cage of Eden occur?

Tags: cage-of-eden

In *Cage of Eden*, near the end, instead of plane crash in the beginning, we learn that the students

> did not crash on an uninhabited island but went into the future. It isn't clear how they actually get to this *future*.

I am not sure if I just missed the part where they explained a bit how they got there or if it is just not properly explained.

How did the events at the end of *Cage of Eden* occur?

Comment: Added a bounty on this, because I'd like a more informative answer - Was it all a dream of his mothers? How did the timewarp occur? etc

Comment: i agree with the future thingy and with the ending being really rushed is a butt hurt, well then in my own theory, if they sail out they will have a chance to go back in the real world and thus see their families:3 it's all about the mystery baby! all love to (cage of eden) almost close to masterpiece but geniusly made is already a very high remarks.

Comment: didn't they hint that all of them ended up being clones like the other animals?

Comment: regretfully there is not going to be another season or continuation for this manga. when I read it i searched around to find out when will the rest of it come out or is there going to be an anime, unfortunately I found out that the manga was not very successful at the time and they rushed the author to end his work earlier than he wanted so they can publish another manga.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is never explained in the manga how they get

> to the future.

When they describe the incident, it looks like a wormhole that caused a big disruption in time.

> In physics, an Einstein-Rosen Bridge (or wormhole) is a hypothetical topological feature of spacetime that would be, fundamentally, a "shortcut" through spacetime.<sup>[[ref]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole)</sup>

Comment: To add, it looks like the author was going for a "Bermuda Triangle" type of plot. Wherein the story revolved around the people who actually got lost. "What if you can see what happened to them?" Something like that. *sorry edited out the spoiler*

Answer (score 2):

I'm still confused about what happened myself, but considering all the real-world historical facts the talked about, like the limestone cave being like Cappadocia, the disappearance of Eiken and the others at the Monument being like the [Angikuni Village Disappearance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angikuni_Lake), then the way they were transported to the future could be the [Dragon's Triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Sea).

The Dragon's Triangle is an area of ocean south of Japan that is like the Bermuda Triangle. There are cases of boats of all sizes disappearing never to be heard from. The Island that CoE takes place on is located in the Dragon's Triangle, from what I could see from the map Mariya showed of where the plane went down, so despite them not talking about it in the manga, that seems like the most plausible reason for the time travel. Maybe Yoshinobu Yamada had planed on that being the reason but was unable to fit it in for the same reason the ending was so rushed.

Answer (score 1):

So I heard this from a friend. This is only a theory.

Since the kids are on an island with memorials of themselves, there is a possibility of the entire cast not being the actual people themselves but actually clones. With the technology of being able to bring back extinct animals,  they probably could also create clones of the deceased people using their DNA.

Also, the mother spoke about the island being a paradise, but since the cast is "dead", it could mean that they were planning on cloning the victims on the island in the first place. The scientists hoped to make it paradise but with their death and the help of the "terrorists", the extinct animals were able to escape into the wild. =

This theory also has a lot of holes (the plane, age, etc.), but it is a pretty satisfying theory in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

They time travel when they are inside of the plane and they crashed on a island in the future.Otherwise, the world what the world looks like now wouldn't make any sense.

The main character's mother and other scientists who built the island built it in the past. The graves are there because the adults thought that they died in the crash and erected memorials to all the passengers who died.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the idea is that the plane inadvertently disappeared, which caused Akira's mother to continue the Eden Project and eventually create Raika Island, and that one of the company's directors, maybe Sengoku Frey, in a last-ditch attempt to save her dream of the 'paradise' after the biohazard disaster on the island, channelled the company's remaining funds into Time-Travel research, which was completed and used to send the flight into the future to 'save' them, but accidentally causing an infinite time loop in the process.

It would fit, in my opinion, with Sengoku Frey's 'acceptance of Yuna's heart', and would be the most probable theory.

Too bad that's how publishers go - cutting off a series' lifeline so they can do other stories. Or perhaps, the author's idea was going to be much more ambitious, but wasn't given the time to finish it.